# Create continuous-aggregates from base table

Tags: postgresql, timescaledb

i have a base table which update with more than 500 item per second and whole table contain almost 500 million data. how create continuous-aggregates from this table by interval 1m?
if i create the Create continuous-aggregates will it goes to loop? because handle this much data will take time while in this time new data comes

i want a way to create continuous-aggregates first calculate all data and don't look at update. then update news

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use the `WITH NO DATA` option to later `refresh_continuous_aggregates` only of the data you want. You can select the begin and end of the timeframe that you want to update.
Example:

```sql
CALL refresh_continuous_aggregate('caggs_name', '2020-01-01', '2020-02-01');
```

See the API docs [here](https://docs.timescale.com/api/latest/continuous-aggregates/refresh_continuous_aggregate/).